# OnClick function on <a> tag is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to navigate via onclick of a `<a>` tag but its not working here the what i am trying

### html

```
<a id="openPopup"  href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>
```

### Script

```
$.('#openPopup').click(function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
        });
```

It shows the popup properly but doesn't not navigate to the google..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what's the dot represent..? remove that.

```
   $.('#openPopup').click(function() {
//--^
```

And also use `event.preventDefault()` inside the click handler to avoid its default action

Full code,

```
$('#openPopup').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

remove dot from `$.('#openPopup')` and use `$('#openPopup')`;

Use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$('#openPopup').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$('#openPopup').click(function() { // remove '.' from the code
   window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
});
```

That period sign was causing the trouble with your code.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#openPopup').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
 });
```